# execute a python method in X parallel sub-processes where x is configurable

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess

I'm not a python expert,
and I'm trying to implement the functionality in subject.

I know how to use a functionality which executes methods in parallel.
E.g.

```
def main():
    run_in_parallel(A,B)

def A():
    while True:
        print("A")

def B():
    while True:
        print("B")

def run_in_parallel(*fns):
    proc = []
    for fn in fns:
        p = Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I can't figure out how can I execute method A in 10 / 20 / 100 / ... parallel sub processes.

Assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to return something from the parallel functions?

Comment: @Will no need for return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to run function A 10/20/100... times in parallel subprocesses? If yes then you can create 20 subprocesses like this:

```
def main():
    run_in_parallel(A, 20)

def A():
    while True:
        print("A")

def run_in_parallel(fn, proc_count):
    proc = []
    for _ in range(proc_count):
        p = Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: this makes sense, however when I try to execute it in more then one subprocess, I'm getting an error. can you have a look?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, what you are looking for is a threadpool/processpool, where you can define the number of workers, and then just apply functions asynchronously with them. Python has that [built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool). Instead of opening a new process you can just use `pool.apply_async`.

For example:

```
def run_in_parallel(fn, times=10):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(times)
    [pool.apply_async(fn) for _ in range(times)]
```

Comment: can you provide an example? pseudo for what i need is something like: num_of_subprocesses = 10 execute_method_in_parallel(num_of_subprocesses)

This should invoke method A in 10 parallel sub processes.